# Where is Profiling configured in a Windows Azure cloud project?

Tags: windows, azure, profiling

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh369930.aspx) shows how to enable profiling from the Publish Windows Azure Application dialog.

How can I configure profiling without using that dialog?

I looked through my service configuration and service definition files, and I can't find any settings related to profiling.  The checkbox and radio buttons in the Publish dialog has to be configuring some setting file somewhere; I just can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

I found it.  Profiling is indeed configured in a settings file somewhere.

In case anyone has this same question, here's the answer:

Inside the Azure project directory, there's a folder called "Profiles".  Inside that folder are some .azurePubxml files that (it looks like) correspond one-to-one with your service configurations.

Inside those files is a setting `<AzureEnableProfiling>True</AzureEnableProfiling>` that can be set to True or False.

So that's how you can turn Profiling on and off, without needing to use the gui tool for publishing to Azure.